# What is meant by "Swing components are light-weight"? 

Tags: java, swing, terminology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Swing components are light-weight ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416947/swing-components-are-light-weight)

what do we mean when we say that :

"**swing components are light weight**"

if swing components are light weight then what are heavy weight.?

Explain very clearly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/416947/swing-components-are-light-weight explained in detail i guess

Answer (score 4):

AWT components are heavyweight. AWT components are considered "heavyweight" because each AWT component will cause the allocation of a native peer component, whereas Swing components do not. Read the "Relationship to AWT" section http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_(Java).

Comment: This matters in operating systems with legacy APIs, because UI components are expensive there. In Windows, f.i., calls to one of the core OS components, handle pools, double indirection, locking, and large amounts of memory allocation and deallocation, and even file-system access are involved when using the legacy APIs. None of that happens if an application draws most of it's GUI in user space (something that couldn't be done before reaching the right point in available RAM and CPU speed).

Answer (score 0):

Light weight means a Swing JComponent doesn't correspond to an OS Window or similar, but is just a bunch of pixels painted on the top level component.