# Disposing a Modal dialog using a condition

Tags: java, swing, jtable, joptionpane

I have a modal jDialog that i wish to dispose when a particular condition is met after showing the error message in another Dialog using JOptionPane. I have tried to use the dispose() method after the JOptionPane dialog but my modal dialog still opens up.
The relevant part of my code is below:

```
    import java.awt.Component;
    import java.sql.*;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

    public class ReviewPatients extends javax.swing.JDialog {

    public ReviewPatients(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
    super(parent, modal);

    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {

        },
        new String [] {
            "Name", "Address", "Number"
        }
    ) {
        Class[] types = new Class [] {
java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.Integer.class
        };
        boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
            false, false, false
        };

        public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return types [columnIndex];
        }

        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return canEdit [columnIndex];
        }
    });
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 1012, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 526, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();


    jScrollPane1.setVisible(false);

e: 
{    
           try
            {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/doctor","root","Pranav123");
            String query="SELECT * FROM records_table WHERE Name LIKE 'some_name';";
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs= st.executeQuery(query);



            DefaultTableModel tmodel = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();

                //Clearing the table
                int rows=tmodel.getRowCount();
                while(rows>0)
                {
                    tmodel.removeRow(0);
                    rows--;
                }
                jTable1.setModel(tmodel);

            while(rs.next())
            {

                //Putting data into table
                tmodel.addRow(new Object[] {rs.getString(1),rs.getString(2),rs.getInt(4)});
                jTable1.setModel(tmodel);
            }

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("Error: "+e);
            }

        if(jTable1.getRowCount()==0)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "No records exist!");
                dispose();
                break e;
            }



         //Showing data   
        jScrollPane1.setVisible(true);


}    

public static void main(String args[]) {
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            ReviewPatients dialog = new ReviewPatients(new javax.swing.JFrame(), true);
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

e is the label that I have used to exit the block whenever an error occurs.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you share a minimal testable code?

Comment: @Braj I have added more of my code.

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: @trashgod I have included an mcve.

Comment: I've updated your example and queried my own database below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All static methods in JOptionPane create modal dialogs, i.e., execution of the code stops until the user dismisses the dialog box. If you want to create non-modal dialogs, use JDialog directly. Refer to [Java Swing Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more information.

**Updated:**

If I am not wrong, you are trying to do is to **NOT** show the `ReviewPatients` dialog at all when there are no records. If that is the case, the simplest solution is to just replacing `dispose()` with `System.exit(1)`.

A better solution is check whether there are records in the database, and:

- If there are records, create the `ReviewPatients` dialog and populate the table with the data.
- If there is no record, display the `JOptionPane` to inform the user there is no record, and terminate the program.

On a separate note: though permissible, try not to mix AWT components with Swing components (refer to [another Stack Overflow answer for the reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040131/swing-and-awt-mixing-is-bad-but-still-done-why#12040366)).

Comment: I understand this but after the user dismisses the dialog box, my modal dialog still shows up

Comment: System.exit(1) won't work as I have other frames in my application and the method will end the entire application. The other solution is the key! I used the count() method of sql. Thanka a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

I see a number of problems, some of which may be relevant:

- Repeated calls to `setModel()` are unnecessary and may notify the listening table unexpectedly.
- A simpler way to clear the `DefaultTableModel` is via `setRowCount(0)`.
- Instead of checking the *view* for success, check the *model*; even better, just show the `JOptionPane` in the exception handler.
- The dialog's parent should probably be a `JFrame`.
- Also consider updating the table's model using [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).

As tested:

```
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

/**
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/24220593/230513
 */
public class ReviewPatients extends javax.swing.JDialog {

    public ReviewPatients(JFrame parent, boolean modal) {
        super(parent, modal);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        JTable table = new JTable();
        table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
            new Object[][]{},
            new String[]{
                "Name", "Address", "Number"
            }
        ) {
            Class[] types = new Class[]{
                java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.Integer.class
            };
            boolean[] canEdit = new boolean[]{
                false, false, false
            };

            @Override
            public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return types[columnIndex];
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                return canEdit[columnIndex];
            }
        });
        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(table, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 800, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(table, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 400, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        try {
            Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:file:~/src/java/jdbc/test;IFEXISTS=TRUE", "sa", "");
            String query = "SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER;";
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
            DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
            model.setRowCount(0);
            while (rs.next()) {
                model.addRow(new Object[]{rs.getInt(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3)});
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No records exist!");
        }
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame();
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.pack();
                f.setVisible(true);
                ReviewPatients dialog = new ReviewPatients(f, true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry i do not understand. If the table model has no rows, an exception wouldn't be thrown right? So how will the error dialog appear? And, in your code, i do not understand how the modal dialog will be disposed if there are no records.

Comment: Yes, you may want to distinguish between a query error versus a query that returns no rows. If you mean `dialog`, you can use the approach shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5540802/230513).