# How light-weight is a Swing Component?

Tags: java, swing, awt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Swing components are light-weight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416947/swing-components-are-light-weight)

There are different answers for this, but the thing is, that every place has explained it just saying AWT using a native window for every component and Swing has not been used in those examples, how does it work in Swing?

Comment: Another stack overflow question addresses this issue well.
See [The Swing Components are light weight post][1]



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/416947/swing-components-are-light-weight

Comment: Another stack overflow question addresses this issue well.
See [The Swing Components are light weight post][1]



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/416947/swing-components-are-light-weight

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure I completely understand your question but here goes:

Most Swing components are **entirely lightweight** - they are implemented with pure Java code. As far as the OS is concerned, the Swing lightweight components don't exist.

However you should know that Swing always uses **at least one** native component (usually the top-level window). The rest of Swing (all the lightweight components) are implemented so that they perform painting within this native component.